# Using username column instead of id?

Tags: sql, database, pseudocode

This is a setup for a database for user management I've found somewhere on the internet (written in pseudocode). While it seems perfectly fine, I don't understand why the `users` table has an `id` as well as a unique, not null `username` column. Couldn't I just use the username as the `id` (primary key)?

```
users
(
  id integer primary key,
  username varchar(100) not null unique key,
  pwd varchar(50) not null
);

user_roles
(
  user_id integer not null,
  role_id integer not null,
  unique key (user_id, role_id),
  index(user_id)
);

roles
(
  id integer primary key,
  role varchar(100) not null unique key
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always fall back to Kimberly L. Tripp's [recommendations for a clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx) (which, by default, is the primary key in SQL Server).

Her criteria are that the clustering key should be:

- Unique (tie between ID and name)
- Narrow (+1 for ID)
- Static (*possible* +1 for ID, depending on whether name is allowed to change)
- Ever-increasing (*possible* +1 for ID, depending on how it's implemented, using an IDENTITY column here would be the ideal case)

Answer (score 4):

Yes you could use username. The problem is that a potentially volatile primary keys are a pain because you need to cascade the change to all the FK's.

Also using integers in joins tend to perform better

You should note that what makes a key volatility is somewhat subjective

Also as JNK mentions there is an optimization to be had when a clustered indexes (typically also the PK) is an incremental int See Kimberly L. Tripp's article [The Clustered Index Debate Continues](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)

Comment: +1 - Also also since it is  your clustered index key in SQL Server insert performance will be a lot better with an incremental int instead of a randomly-place varchar.

Comment: @JNK thanks forgot about that one. Updated the answer to include that bit

Answer (score 4):

You could (use the `user_id` as the *primary key*).

The only snag I see is this: If ever a `user_id` needs to be changed (*Stephanie Smith* gets married to some guy named *Johnson* and needs her `user_id` changed), then it is less database maintenance.

Where I work, someone setup our database to use `user_id` as the *primary key* years ago. Changing that now would be a nightmare!

Plus, an `int` is faster to search and can be auto generated.

Answer (score 2):

That would make joining to it inefficient: `int`s are much smaller than `varchar(100)` so the index will be smaller, and quicker. Normally the Primary Key will be the Clustered index of the table.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the username as primary key. Maybe this example use the id column for a better performance. Is faster to search an Int Column than a text one, i guess. Also in user_role table there is a foreign_key user_id. Does not make sense use a string(100) in this case, as a foreign_key.

Answer (score 2):

At the high level your talking Natural vs. Surrogate Keys here.  There are trade offs, both of which I think have been mentioned, but if you want additional reading I'd say this link sums it up nicely

["Natural and Surrogate Keys"](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/02/01/surrogate-keys-vs-natural-keys-for-primary-key/)

Comment: +1 Thx for the link, I can every bit of information I can get :-).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the ID is an auto incremental value stored in the database used for referencing in DB scripts, though the username is also unique column. The biggest advantage is your user will not need to remember any numeric number that has been assigned to the system to log into the account rather they can choose their own unique usernames and interact easily.